# How is it possible to do Web development on Chrome, Opera, Chromium?

Tags: google-chrome, iframe, cookies, opera, chromium

For the file protocol, I'm informed that Chrome and its sycophants Chromium and Opera (COC) support neither cookies nor cross-frame file access.

To develop company documentation, I used cookies and cross-frame tables of contents with file:// using Netscape 3 and following. I continue so to use them for my own Web site, biblekjv.com/kjv-fm/startkjv.htm, both to develop that site and also to utilize it daily from my hard disk. Now I use Firefox for those purposes. Firefox and Internet Explorer handle them very well. The COC browsers do not. Why not? Ideally, for Web development and for off-line access to Internet pages, file:// and http:// should function identically. How do COC users develop Web sites? On the Google cloud? Please explain why emasculating file:// features is not a Google ploy to force us to use the Google Internet cloud instead of our own hard disks. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't just create a local web server on your machine. Also you could use localStorage.